# Unable to pass address[] argument from python to solidity

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity

I have a function like this in solidity:

```
function convertEthToTokenUniswap(uint tokenAmount,address[] memory path,uint deadline) public payable {
//can be empty still throws no matching argument types error
}
```

and I'm trying to call it in python, but I don't now how to pass the address[] argument. The compiler breaks on passing the variable as a list like so (in python):

```
path = [ethaddresses.ethToken,ethaddresses.makerToken]
```

the error:

```
ValidationError: 
Could not identify the intended function with name `convertEthToTokenUniswap`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'int'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `convertEthToTokenUniswap`: ['convertEthToTokenUniswap(uint256,address[],uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to pass this kind of argument?
2. If above is possible, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant source code missing. Please edit the equestion and add the relevant source code, otherwise your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Hello Mikko, this concerns a compiler error, the content of the function is not relevant, I have added this in the comment inside the function.

Comment: Youe question has a Python `ValidationError`. If there is a compiler error please post the compiler error.